# Adding custom menu options and removing some default

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

When opening default menu on `WebView` I have some default menus. I wish to remove some like "Share","Select All","Web Search" and leave "Copy", "Paste" and **after** them add some of my menu options. For now I accomplish to remove some and add mine only **before** the "Copy" and "Paste". I have 2 questions:

1. There is a better way to remove items than

   ```
   menu.removeItem(51381251); //Remove Share
   ```

Maybe with the R.id or something? But how can I find it?

2. How to add menu element after the default ones?

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActionModeStarted(ActionMode mode) {
       super.onActionModeStarted(mode);

       MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
       Menu menu = mode.getMenu();

       menu.removeItem(51381251); //Remove Share
       menu.removeItem(51381252); //Remove Select all
       menu.removeItem(51381254); //Remove Web Search

       menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.highlight, menu);

       menu.findItem(R.id.myItem1).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new CustomMenuItemClickListener());
       menu.findItem(R.id.myItem2).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new CustomMenuItemClickListener());
   }
   ```

Current state:
[image]